# Результат работы gnome терминала не выводится в stdout subprocess

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, gnome

```
result = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-e', 'java -jar DocSearch.jar "search:' + str(obj) + '" "docs"'], 
                        cwd='/home/search/Dev/searcher/build/dist', universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.communicate())
```

В результате выводит: (' ', null). Хотя в терминале команда выполняется и выводит результат. Но в stdout он не попадает. Такое ощущение что print исполняется не дожидаясь окончания процесса.

Comment: terminal - это же gui-приложение. в его stdout попадает не то, что отображается в самом терминале... Вообще я сомневаюсь, что туда что-то вообще попадает. В stderr да.

Comment: А как тогда получить то, что в самом терминале отображается?

Comment: В терминале запускается интрепретатор(например, bash). Вероятно вам стоит запустить `/bin/bash -c` вместо `gnome-terminal`. Или даже сразу `java -jar...`, зачем посредники)

Comment: Дело в том что я использую в команде арабский язык и он не корректно работает в самом bash. Собственно с него я и начинал, только потом на gnome перешел

Comment: Ну, это вам нужно просто подгрузить корректный environment. Посмотрите его в gnome-terminal и задайте для процесса bash/java. Подозреваю, основные опции - это LANG и какой-нибудь LC_ALL..

Comment: В gnome-terminal арабский как то костыльно ставится, изменение языка в окружении спасает со всеми видимо кроме арабского

Comment: Если сможете найти pid интерпретатора в терминале, можете попробовать почитать `/proc/%PID%/fd/1`